# ScrollIntoView in React without refs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, scroll, ref

I have a big list of items / divs that I need to create *programmatically*, and I need to implement scrollIntoView buttons for each them. I know how to do it with refs.

Whether there is an alternative to refs that might be more performant?

Comment: You wouldn't have to use refs if your `onClick` callback uses the event target itself to find (or be) the element to scroll to

Answer (score 1):

I believe something like this will work:

```
onScrollClick(ev) {
    ev.target.scrollIntoView();
}

render() {
    return (
           ... <button onClick={this.onScrollClick}>Scroll This Element Into View</button>
      )
}
```

That assumes you want to scroll the button itself into view. If that's not what you want, you'll have to be specific.

[edit] if it's not the element itself, but one of the elements parents, you can also find a parent with javascript apis, `element.parentElement` -- you can use that as many times as you need to find the relevant element.